# How can I run Socket.io on node with express framework?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to run a websocket using express framework and [socket.io](http://socket.io/docs/#) on node.js.

Here is what I have done

```
var env = require('./config');
var app = require('express').createServer();

var server = app.listen(env.socket.port, env.socket.host, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});


var io = require('socket.io')(app);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Landed!');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });

  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });

});
```

But it is not working! Here is the error that I get

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs>node socket.js
C:\Program Files\nodejs\socket.js:2
var app = require('express').createServer();
                             ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\socket.js:2:30)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `require('express').createServer()` is for very old versions of Express (e.g. 2.x). You should use [this example](http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4) for Express 3.x/4.x:

```
var env = require('./config');

var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(env.socket.port, env.socket.host, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Landed!');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });

  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });

});
```